# class name jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

tying to get the classname which is hidden in this case

```
<div class="hidden" id="tbl1">
    </div>
```

using this

```
alert($("#tbl"+n).attr('class'));
```

It gives me undefined error

Comment: Well, I guess that would be a completely stupid question from my part but: did you actually define the `n` variable somewhere? Because, you know, the error message that you are getting seems kinda pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Can you show the code that defines `n`?

Comment: try `console.log("n is "+n); console.log($("#tbl"+n));`. it will give you the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works here (via jsFiddle) just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/TybLz/

```
var n = 1;

alert($("#tbl"+n).attr('class'));
```